# How do I resolve "The name was not provided by any .service files" when connecting Galaxy Tab A via USB?

Tags: debian, usb, mtp

I am running Debian Linux 11 with LXDE and I am trying to connect a Galaxy Tab A tablet.

When I do, I get the Removable Medium Is Inserted dialog with the type of medium being "removable disk" and the only action available is "Open in File Manager".  I click OK and I get an Error dialog box with the do-not-enter icon and the message

`The name :1.31 was not provided by any .service files`

It is always this message (with that specific number).

The file manager opens up to "mtp://SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_b269fabb" but it is always empty (there should be a Card directory and a Tablet directory).

What does the error message mean?  Is Linux looking for a driver that is not installed?  If so, which one and how do I install it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just in case you'd have missing required components, I'd try installing mtp-related tools such as: jmtpfs, mtp-tools, libmtp-runtime  . Not tested.

Comment: This seems to have worked.  Could you post this as an answer so I can mark it, please?

Comment: In my case I just had to do `nautilus -q` and it worked after, it was on ubuntu though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a common [library used to handle the Media Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol#Unix-like_systems). Installing various related MTP tools (and thus their dependencies) will ensure that the actually needed libraries and other required components are present.

[From](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/715844/how-do-i-resolve-the-name-was-not-provided-by-any-service-files-when-connecti?noredirect=1#comment1356508_715844) [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/715844/how-do-i-resolve-the-name-was-not-provided-by-any-service-files-when-connecti?noredirect=1#comment1356812_715844) it appears installing some or any of packages [`jmtpfs`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/jmtpfs), [`mtp-tools`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/mtp-tools), [`libmtp-runtime`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/libmtp-runtime) is enough to provide the needed libraries and other code in place for LXDE to use it properly.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo killall gvfsd
```

Then also kill your file manager.

No need to reboot anything. Just plug again and open your file manager.